# What is the difference between ObjectProperty and Binder in Vaadin?

Tags: java, binding, vaadin

I'm going to read me in binder. Now I have three options in vaadin to binding Data. Once is with the `ObjectProperty` and `setPropertyDataSource().` The Second one is to make a bean class and set it in a BeanFieldGroup and the third one is with a Binder. 
What is the difference of it?
 Which one uses for what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectProperty, BeanFieldGroup and in general FieldGroup is concept of the Vaadin 7 for binding data between the bean and the fields.

Binder on the other hand is new concept in Vaadin 8 (and also in platform versions 10 onwards) that replaces the above. So if you are going to develop the application with Vaadin 8, the Binder is the way to go.